# PHP regular expression Get html tag end with difference way

Tags: php, regex, operators

First, sorry for my English, it not good.

I have Table as below.

```
 <table>
  <tr class="_in" id="1">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content
         <h1>content h1</h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="_in" id="2">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>content</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <h2>content h2</h2>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="_in" id="3">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>content</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <h3>content h3</h3>
    </td>   
  </tr>
  <tr class="_in" id="4">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content
        <h1>content h3</h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="_in" id="5">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content
        <h1>content h1</h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you see, i want use regular expression to get tr has class="_in", but in tr have another table and in that table have another tr tag. beside that, tr has class="_in" end with many way.
as you can see it can end with `</h1></td></tr>` or `</h2></td></tr>` or `</h3></td></tr>`

My solution is use or operator but don't have result, below are my code

```
$html=file_get_contents("vnair3.txt");
$parten='/<tr\sclass=\"_in\"[^>]*>.*(?:<\/h1>|<\/h2>|<\/h3>)\s+<\/td>\s+<\/tr>/isU';
preg_match_all($parten,$html,$output);
print_r($output);
```

Please help me get each tr tag has class="_in" to each element in ouput array.
i use php.
Thanks all

Comment: Not sure if i understood you but... can you check [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: No. Stop. Don't use a Regular Expression. For the love of God, please resist the urge. I know that it seems like a good idea, but it isn't. Just listen to @JoseAdrian and use a DOM Parser. Your soul depends on it.

Comment: thanks jose and maio, i'll try it, but have another way use regular expression to finish it?

Comment: Mr.Lak, you will never achieve what you want with regex, it's simply not realistic. You are much better following @JoseAdrians advise. If you're not convinced, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Why would one use @JoseAdrian's suggestion when DOMDocument is in a standard PHP install?

Comment: I think he is saying to use a Dom parser... not necessarily the library I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Modify Your Code and you get class="_in" in each tr

```
<?php
$html=file_get_contents('vnair3.txt');
$output=str_replace("<tr","<tr class='_in' ",$html,$count);
//echo $output;
print_r($output);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, slurp the HTML into a DOMDocument.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument::loadHTML($html_string);
```

Then find all your `<TR>` elements.

```
$trs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr')
```

Then iterate over them

```
foreach($trs as $tr) {
    $classes = $tr->getAttribute('class');
    $classes .= " _tr ";
    $tr->setAttribute('class', $classes);
}
```

Then export the string

```
$html = $dom->saveHTML()
```

For reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php